# Does float and double datatype work in gcc compilers?

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I've written a code for the following program but the output seems to be wrong.
Question:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/plus-minus

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

     int N,num,i,cp=0,cn=0,cz=0;
     double fp,fn,fz;
     scanf("%d",&N);
     for(i=0;i<N;i++)
     {
         scanf("%d",&num);
         if(num>0)
            cp=cp+1;
        else if(num==0)
            cz=cz+1;
        else
            cn=cn+1;
    }
    fp=cp/N;
    fn=cn/N;
    fz=cz/N;
    printf("%lf\n%lf\n%lf",fp,fn,fz);
    return 0;
}
```

The Output comes as:

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: I like how you obviously are writing your tenth C program or so and assume that you have found a bug in GCC when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Istructions:

```
fp=cp/N;
fn=cn/N;
fz=cz/N;
```

Are performed as integer division.

Change your code to:

```
 fp=(double)(cp)/(double)(N);
 fn=(double)(cn)/(double)(N);
 fz=(double)(cz)/(double)(N);
```

Comment: No point in casting both sides of the division, very verbose code.

Comment: @unwind I chose to be verbose in this case to give OP indication that there are integers on both side of formula.

Answer (score 0):

For correct result `cast` these expression's to `double`-

```
                     like this
fp=cp/N;         //  fp=(double)cp/N;
fn=cn/N;         //  fn=(double)cn/N;
fz=cz/N;         //  fz=(double)cz/N;
```

[Working code](https://ideone.com/YOIgwF)

In previous case if `cp(or cn or cz)` is less than `N` then due to integer division you will get `0`(fraction part will be discarded). Therefore m these casts .

Another method would be to use all variables as `double` .

Answer (score 0):

you are doing an integer division which creates only integer results. If you want to calculate floating point results you need to perform floating point divisions.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;
int c = a / b;
```

// c is now 0 -> integer division

```
double i = 1.0;
double j = 3.0;
double k = i / j;
```

// k is now 0.3333333 -> floating point division